# Snowflake Numeric value '' is not recognized

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Please help me with error 'Numeric value '' is not recognized'.

In Snowflake i am having a variable day_minus which holds a number, using this i want to return date value of current_date minus the value given in the variable.
If there is Null or empty passed in the variable i want to get current date minus 1.

For this i have written a code like below. But it throws me an error Numeric value '' is not recognized

But it throws an

set day_minus=7;

SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, concat('-',nvl(nullif(try_to_number($day_minus) ,''),1)),current_date() );

Can you please correct me where i am doing mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use case statement
SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, concat('-',nvl(case when $Units ='' then 1 else $Units end ,1)),current_date() );

Answer (score 0):

If you use concat then the result is always going to be a string. If you want to set the "default" value to -1 then just put -1 in your code.

The try_to_* functions take a string as their input so you'd need to make your variable a string to make this work e.g.

```
set day_minus='7';
```

You don't need nullif at all. So the final version would be something like:

```
set day_minus='7';

DATEADD(DAY, nvl(try_to_number($day_minus),-1),current_date() );
```

Comment: HI @Nick The above  will always add the  variable with current date. I need the values of current_date minus variable.

Comment: Just make the variable '-7' if you want to subtract - if you do this in the variable then your code will allow you to add or subtract. If you definitely always want to subtract, and don't want to use negative values in your variables then just multiple the number by -1

Comment: HI Nick lets say i am passing the variable using procedure, there i will supply only number without +/- signs. what should i do in this scenario.

Comment: If you want the number to always subtract then you'd need to code the SQL in your procedure to do just that. You'd need to validate the input and, if it was negative, either reject it or convert it to a positive number - up to you how you handle it

Comment: NickW i need to minus the curent date with variable value. Without minus i couldnt able to subtract current date with variable value.

Comment: So just multiple the variable by -1 after you've converted it to a number